# Flutter: How can I get list of device locales before building starts?

Tags: flutter, locale, setlocale

I want to internationalize my application. To ease translations, I want to use i18n_extension package.

I need to get the list of device locales (any device, even web) before any widget building process starts.

This is required to initially set the correct locale (which can be taken from a server) both for `I18n` and for `Localizations` (in `WidgetsApp`).

The only way I found to get the list of device locales is:

```
MaterialApp(
  localeListResolutionCallback: (deviceLocales, appLocales) => myLocaleResolution(deviceLocales, appLocales),
  locale: thisAppsLocale,
  home: I18n(
    child: MyHomePage(),
    initialLocale: thisAppsLocale, ),
```

Method `myLocaleResolution` sets `thisAppsLocale`. Method is invoked once at startup and when the user changes the device locale. So `thisAppsLocale` is only available **after** the first build process and cannot be used to set `locale` and `initialLocale`. Using `setState()` within `myLocaleResolution` throws an exception on startup invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.locales`:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: window.locale,
      supportedLocales: window.locales,
      home: Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```

The `window` singleton gives you access to the [Window](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window-class.html) class.

Comment: Works perfectly. Can even be used in separate classes without any BuildContext.